# Dropdown creation to autofill entire table into another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to copy data from one worksheet to another (within the same workbook) from 'Source' to '48597' based on selection from a dropdown list.

- In '48597', information is displayed across columns B:L.
- If 'Goods Receipt' has been selected in a dropdown list (setup in Col.B), then I want all cells from 'Source' within columns A:K AND rows 4:12 to populate into '48597' from 'Source'.
- And in the same order, sizing etc.

How please?

48597: 
[image: 48597]

Source:
[image: Source]

Comment: How often does action need to be done? It does take that long to record a macro to copy then unhide-all and delete unwanted columns.

Comment: Hi. There is not a set frequency unfortunately. It would be a weekly process perhaps. What is it you have in mind?

Comment: Enable Record Macro , create it manually after practising with the most efficient keystrokes rather than MOUSE (maybe?) then save as a hockey and try it out.  You may want to learn some hotkeys for creating new worksheets and switch right to next worksheet if the hotkeys exist.  I”m not a macro guru.